# Is it a correct implementation of interlocked singly linked list in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, race-condition

I have the following implementation of interlocked singly linked list using C++11 atomics:

```
struct notag {};

template<class T, class Tag=notag>
struct s_list_base
{
};

template<class T, class Tag = notag>
struct s_list : s_list_base<T, Tag>
{
    s_list_base<T, Tag> *next_ptr;
};

template<bool auto_destruct, class T, class Tag = notag>
class atomic_s_list
{
    struct s_head : s_list_base<T, Tag>
    {
        std::atomic<s_list_base<T, Tag > *> next_ptr { this };
    };
    using LinkType = s_list<T, Tag> *;

    s_head head;

public:
    atomic_s_list() = default;
    atomic_s_list(const atomic_s_list &) = delete;
    atomic_s_list &operator =(const atomic_s_list &) = delete;

    ~atomic_s_list()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear() noexcept
    {
        if (auto_destruct)
        {
            T *item;
            do
            {
                item = pop();
                delete item;
            } while (item);
        }
        else
            head.next_ptr = &head;
    }

    void push(T *pItem) noexcept
    {
        auto p = static_cast<LinkType>(pItem);
        auto phead = head.next_ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        do
        {
            p->next_ptr = phead;
        } while (!head.next_ptr.compare_exchange_weak(phead, p));
    }

    T *pop() noexcept
    {
        auto result = head.next_ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        while (!head.next_ptr.compare_exchange_weak(result, static_cast<LinkType>(result)->next_ptr))
            ;
        return result == &head ? nullptr : static_cast<T *>(result);
    }
};
```

The problem is that in real program I have several concurrently running threads that take an object from this list with `pop`, work with it and then put it back with `push` and it seems like I have a race when sometimes two threads end up getting the same object from a list.

I have tried to make a simple example out of that program to illustrate a race.
Here it is:

```
struct item : s_list<item>
{
    std::atomic<int> use{ 0 };
};

atomic_s_list<true, item> items;

item *allocate()
{
    auto *result = items.pop();
    if (!result)
        result = new item;
    return result;
}

void free(item *p)
{
    items.push(p);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    static const int N = 20;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
        {
            while (true)
            {
                auto item = allocate();
                if (0 != item->use.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed))
                    std::terminate();

                item->use.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                free(item);
            }
        }));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20min);
}
```

So the question is: is this implementation of interlocked singly-linked list correct?

Comment: Might it be an [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I can confirm that I face with an [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).

It appears like no one should ever trust this simple interlocked singly linked list implementation on modern hardware (with lots of hardware threads) and highly-contended interlocked lists.

After considering implementing the tricks described in Wikipedia article, I have decided to use boost implementation (see [boost::lockfree::stack](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/stack.html)) as it seems like having good efforts on fighting ABA problem.

For now my test code does not fail, and neither does the original program.

Comment: https://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs

Answer (score 0):

Is not a correct implementation!

1. thread A and thread B call pop; A and B get the same "result" -> head.next_ptr
2. thread A modify the memory.
3. thread B read "result->next_ptr" get INCORRECT DATA
4. thread A call push. head.next_ptr == "result" NOW!
5. thread B call compare_exchange_weak; head.next_ptr update with the INCORRECT DATA